# children and padding isnt defined in listView flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

[children and padding isnt defined in listView flutter]

return ListView(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),

children: [
Container(
height: 50,
color: Colors.amber[600],
child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
),
Container(
height: 50,
color: Colors.amber[500],
child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
),
Container(
height: 50,
color: Colors.amber[100],
child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
),
],
);

Comment: where's is this return? void buld(context)?

Comment: I copiedyour code and it works fine. Are you  using the listview in  the buildcontext of a stateless/stateful widget?

Comment: the problem was my class name was ListView when i changed name it work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my class name was ListView when i changed name it work properly.

we must choose names that diffrent from dart flutter classes